# How do I get all timestamps after a specified timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am making a chat program and I want to find all timestamps that are greater than a timestamp in a mysql query. I currently have this query

```
SELECT Message, SendTime, Sender FROM ChatMessages WHERE ((Recipient=$me AND Sender=$talkTo) OR (Sender=$me AND Recipient=$talkTo)) AND
```

I am making it check for new chat messages and I want my query only to return new ones. I have a timestamp of when I last checked for messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this:

```
SendTime > yourTime
```

at the end of your AND condition to produce the desired result.

Comment: Its to prevent you from doing code only answers, your not meant to pad it out with why you can't enter less then 30 chars you're meant to explain what the OP is doing wrong and/or how you solution fixes their problem. You should know this being a 2+ year user. Have a little read of [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before taking the time to answer.

Comment: Its also poor form that the OP has to improve your answer. -1 @MatthiasMoritz +1 OP

Comment: Can I give the timestamp as a number. Eg. SendTime > 1514117215?